# Handler function for radio button created with gradio function in R package gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I am trying to create radio buttons for an R GUI application using the function gradio in the gWidgets package in R.  Here is a simple example of R code that I use to create such a button, which offers the user an option to choose between "Choice 1" and "Choice 2".

```
require(gWidgets)

require("RGtk2")

options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

radio_button <- gradio(c("Choice 1","Choice 2"),
                         selected=1, index=FALSE,
                         horizontal=FALSE, 
                         container=gwindow(), 
                         handler=function(h,...){
                          if (svalue(h$obj)=="Choice 1"){
                              print("Do something")
                          } else { 
                           print("Do something else")
                          }
                          }
                         )
```

The problem that I have is that the handler function associated with the radio button only works as intended when the user actively switches from the default choice for the radio button (Choice 1) to the other available choice (Choice 2).

However, if the default choice (Choice 1) is left "as is" by the user, the handler function does not recognize what the value of this default choice is.

Is there any way to "force" the handler function to recognize the value of the default choice for a radio button created with gradio?  I suspect that this value only gets recognized when the user actively clicks on an option other than the default, but it seems counterintuitive that the default option would not be recognized.

Note that I have encountered the same (odd?) behaviour for the gcheckboxgroup() function, which is intended to produce a group of check boxes.

Any help for solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Isabella

Answer (score 0):

Here a workaround. Yous set the the default value to the desired value using `svalue` like this :

```
svalue(radio_button, index=TRUE) <- 1  ## by index
```

the all code becomes :

```
radio_button <- gradio(c("Choice 1","Choice 2"),
                       selected=2, index=FALSE,
                       horizontal=FALSE, 
                       container=gwindow(), 
                       handler=function(h,...){
                         if (svalue(h$obj)=="Choice 1"){
                           print("Do something")
                         } else { 
                           print("Do something else")
                         }
                       }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are getting at is handlers only respond to events. The solution by @agstudy to call svalue should work in most cases, as the underlying widget gets changed, but may not work with all the widgets. You can force it by leaving the handler as a function you can call separately.